# Camera permissions error on VideoAsk embed on my website

Tags: wordpress, permissions, embed, camerapermission

I recently upgraded to the Grow plan and added more slides to my VideoAsk. Now I am getting a permissions error on my iOS/Mac devices when I copy the embed code to my website. Would anyone know how to fix this?

I purged the cache and it was working immediately after, but then I just tried it 1 hour later and it has the same error.